# Node.js MySQL model designing

Tags: mysql, node.js, model

I'm developing a node.js application using MySQL database but I'm stuck with making models on the node.js side of my application. I've used Mongoose before to produce schemas and use models to do database functions but i couldn't find such support for MySQL. Can anyone suggest a proper way to isolate my database functions in node.js like I could do with Mongoose. here's my app.js and users model i'm using right now.

app.js

```
var express= require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var UserModel= require("./models/User.js")
var app=express();

var sql = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "1234",
    database: "dricm"
});

sql.connect(function (err) {
    if(err){
        console.log("error");
    }else{
        console.log("connected");
    }
});

app.set("views", "./views");

app.use(express.static("node_modules/bootstrap/dist"));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render("signup.jade");
});

app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    var obj= {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    UserModel.createUser(obj);
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("server running at 3000");
});
```

User.js (probable model)

```
var mysql= require("mysql");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

var sql = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "1234",
    database: "dricm"
});

sql.connect(function (err) {
    if(err){
        console.log("error");
    }else{
        console.log("connected");
    }
});

var User= {

}

User.createUser = function createUser(newUser) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password,salt, function (err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            var query = sql.query("INSERT INTO USERS set ?", newUser, function (err, res) {
                console.log(query);
                if(err) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
                else{

                    console.log(res.insertId);
                }
            });
        });
    });

}

module.exports= User;
```

Comment: [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) has a pretty good model framework if you need it, or a nice database layer if you don't. Not sure what `set ?` is supposed to mean here, as usually it's `SET x=?,y=?, ...` or more typically `(name, ...) VALUES (?, ...)`

Comment: @tadman `set ?` substitutes comma-separated lists of key=value pairs if the parameter is a dictionary, see also [the documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values), where it's used as an example.

Comment: @Tanmoy [node-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql) seems to add some modeling functionality on top of mysql (I actually found this post when researching this myself), although I don't yet fully understand it.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks for clarifying. Never seen it done that way before.

Answer (score 20):

What you are looking for is called an ORM (Object-relational mapping) [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) is one for MongoDB (Which is a NOSQL document oriented database)

There are other ORMs for relational databases that work with Node.js, The most popular right now is [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) which I have personally used and recommend.

With Sequelize you can put your models in different files just like Mongoose however in order to load them on, you need to add them with a simple script inside your index.js

Imagine the following Workspace:

```
--models/
----User.js
----Permissions.js
--index.js
```

And your model definitions should be something like this:

User.js

```
const UserModel = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const {INTEGER, STRING, FLOAT, BOOLEAN, DATE} = Sequelize
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        UserId: {type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        Username: {type: STRING, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false},
        Password: STRING
    })
    return User
}

module.exports = UserModel
```

Permissions.js

```
const PermissionsModel = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const {INTEGER, STRING, FLOAT, BOOLEAN, DATE} = Sequelize
    const Permissions = sequelize.define('Permissions', {
        Role: {type: STRING, allowNull: false},
        ControllerAddress: {type: STRING, allowNull: false}
    })
    return Permissions
}

module.exports = PermissionsModel
```

Now you need to use the following script to use them inside your index.js

```
let normalizedPath = require('path').join(__dirname, "models")
    require('fs').readdirSync(normalizedPath).forEach((file) => {
        sequelize.import('./models/' + file)
    })
    let {User, Permissions} = sequelize.models
```

Now you can use the User and Permissions instances to control them and call functions like:

```
User.create({Username, Password})
```